# Does The Fingerprint Scanner Generate The Same Key For The Same Finger?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I was looking at the fingerprint documentation and I see that you cannot log a 'finger'. Instead, you have to have a key generated from the TEE that authenticates the application lock.

What I was wondering was if the key generated was unique every time you 'logged in' by using the fingerprint or if the key was static.

Furthermore, is a different key generated for each finger? For instance, I would like to have my app be tied to only being unlockable by a single finger.

So would it be possible for a user to register using a specific finger, and then only be able to log in with that finger, and then store that key so that I have a unique way to identify my user?

[image: Image Of The Process]

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/issues/20 &
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112066297

Comment: _"What I was wondering was if the key generated was unique every time you 'logged in' by using the fingerprint"_ No, you generate the key once. Each fingerprint authentication is used to authorize the key to be used once (or multiple times during a short amount of time).

Comment: _"would it be possible for a user to register using a specific finger, and then only be able to log in with that finger"_ No. A fingerprint authentication will succeed if the fingerprint presented matches _any_ of the enrolled fingerprints.